# jqgrid hidden column display on sorting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is my `jqgrid`:

```
function gridUser()
{
       var data = ${list};
       jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
       data:data,
       datatype: "local",               
       colNames:['team_name','User Name','Date','Cases'],
       colModel:[
{name:'team_name', width:120, sortable: false,editable: false , align: 'center'},
        {name:'userList', width:120, sortable: true,editable: false , align: 'center' },
           {name:'Date',  width:120, sortable: true,editable: false , align: 'center',sorttype:'date',sortable: true, datefmt: 'm/d/Y'},
           {name:'Cases' ,index:'Cases' , width:80, editable: false , align: 'center',sortable: true,sorttype:'int',summaryType:'sum', summaryTpl : 'Total Cases: {0}'}
           ],
           rowNum: 25,
           width : 450,
           height: 400,
           shrinkToFit: true,
           pager: "#pager2",
           paging: true,
           viewrecords: true,
           gridview: true,
           loadonce:true,              
           rowList : [ 25,50, 75],                 
           sortname : 'userList',
           viewrecords : true,
           sortorder : "asc",                
           rownumbers: true,                  
           altRows:true,                 
           caption: "Statistics",
           grouping: true,
  groupingView : {
  groupField : ['team_name','userList'],
  groupColumnShow : [true],
  groupText : ['<b>{0}</b> - (Total Cases: {Cases})'],
  groupCollapse : false,
   groupOrder: ['asc'],
   groupSummary : [true],
   groupDataSorted : true,
   },                
       });         
       $("#list2").jqGrid("navGrid","#pager2",{add:false, edit:false, del:false});
       $('#list2').hideCol('team_name'); 
}
```

when `JqGrid` display first time it does not display `team_name` column due to `$('#list2').hideCol('team_name');`, 
 But, Whenever i sort other column, it display the column `team_name` which are hidden.
so, my question is
 **how to hide them on other column sorting?**

Thanks in advance, and any help appreciated.

Comment: sorry for being beginner I don't quite understand the `how to hide them on other column sorting?` can you elaborate it for me?. thanks

Comment: read full question. at first time, on grid load, it does not display hidden column `team_name`, but after than when i sort other columns like `Cases` then hidden column also display. but i dont want that, i want to hide that column permanently

Comment: try to add `{name:'team_name', hidden: true` hope it work and try to remove the `$('#list2').hideCol('team_name'); `

Comment: sorry mate if it is not working

Comment: nop it is not working. i tried.

Comment: i am using it in jqgrid v4.3.3

Comment: @Broow, i solved my problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched too much from documentation and other related question and i found solution.
**Problem:-** i'm trying to hide the column on which i'm doing grouping. so when the first time grid load, it does not diplay, but after that when i try to sort column, hidden column display which is `team_name`.
**Solution:-** i changed `groupColumnShow: [true]` to `groupColumnShow: [false]`, because i'm trying to do is hide column on which i'm doing `Grouping`, which solved my problem. everything is working fine.

Comment: Grats :) sorry for late reply